Trying to insert breaks after every element of an array while using HTML
I have an array of elements. I want to be able to insert a break after each element to put into an email via html.
arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var separator = '<br>'
arr = arr.join(separator)



The html code calls for the array.
<p> arr </p>

Unfortunately the output is ... one"Br"two"Br"three.  How do I fix this?

Note that the <br> element should not be used for styling but for breaking inline content. If you want to give spacing to elements, you should use CSS for that.

This should work for you:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="myP"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Getting the html element
        var myP = document.getElementById("myP")
        // Declaring the the array
        var strings = ["one", "two", "three"]
        // Passsing the result to your html tag
        myP.innerHTML=strings.join("<br>")
     </script>

</body>
</html>



